# Split array [0] element and filter, then put into new table

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, text, input-filtering

I try to split sentence to single words and then filter it deleting unwanted words. After that put new content into new table like on picture and jsfiddle demo.

The problem is:

1. I cant split this (i tried .split(" ");  )
2. I have no idea how to make it works for every array (i tried ".map")

Please watch demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/Ashayas/xetqznLb/

Screen: (dont be scary about colors, they show what i want to achieve)
[IMAGE - CONSOLE LOG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWKZX.png)

CODE:

```
// I try to go from arr to tab
arr = [];
arr[0] = ["1. XXX Be yourself; XXX everyone else YYY is XXX already taken."];
arr[1] = ["2. Dont cry ZZZ ZZZ because its over, smile ZZZ because it happened 50.50 30:30"];

tab = [];
tab[0] = ["1.", "Be", "yourself;", "everyone", "else", "is", "already", "taken."];
tab[1] = ["2.", "Dont", "cry", "because", "its", "over", "smile", "because", "it", "happened", "50.50", "30:30"];

var unwanted_content = ["XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ"];
```

Comment: One detail, not sure of what you are trying to achieve, but *arr[0] = ["1. XXX Be yourself; XXX everyone else YYY is XXX already taken."];* does not sets a string in the first position or **arr**, it sets an **array of string** in the first position. Is **arr** an array of strings, or an array of **arrays of strings**?.

Comment: Its array of arrays of strings.

Comment: What are you supposed to save in **tab[i]**, all the filtered strings in **arr[i]**?

Comment: Yes, all filtered strings from arr I want to save in new tab.
In this example are 2 sentences, but I try to make program for all sentences (like 100+ or more).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of what is your expected answer. Meaning, what do you expect to store in **tab** You can use a combination of [join](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp), [includes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp) and [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) methods. You could try something like this

```js
var splitCharacter = " ";
var originalContent = [
  ["1. XXX Be yourself; XXX everyone else YYY is XXX already taken.", "XXX another one"],
  ["2. Dont cry ZZZ ZZZ because its over, smile ZZZ because it happened 50.50 30:30"]
];
var unwantedContent = ["XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ"];

var tab = [];
for (var i = 0; i < originalContent.length; i++) {
  console.log("*********************************");
  tab[i] = originalContent[i].join(" ").split(splitCharacter);
  tab[i] = tab[i].filter(x => !unwantedContent.includes(x));
  console.log("Original and filtered contents: ");
  console.log(originalContent[i]);
  console.log(tab[i])
  console.log("_________________________________");
}
```

Comment: I just change 

var originalContent = arr;

and its exactly what i have tried to achieve. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your array set like that, you could use regex to remove unwanted content

```
var unwanted_content = [/XXX/g, /YYY/g, /ZZZ/g];

var tab = [];
arr.forEach(function(array) {
  var string = array[0];
  unwanted_content.forEach(function(unwanted) {
    string = string.replace(unwanted, '');
  })
  string = string.replace(/ +/g, ' ');
  tab.push(string.split(' '));
})
```

The `replace(/ +/g, ' ')` is to remove duplicated white space, so your array stays the way you want it

Comment: How to add to unwanted_Content symbols "(" or "=" or "]" or "[/url]"?

Comment: /\(/g, /\=/, /\]/, /\[\/url\]/